# Is it possible to create search form for associative Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, search-form

So, here I have several arrays;

```
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Stef","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "vucjak","cijepljen" => "DA","chip" =>"HRV20140115001" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Mia","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "tazmanijska zvijer","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140117002" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Jura","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "ruska plava","cijepljen" => "NE", "chip" =>"HRV20140216003" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Thepas","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "koker","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140823004" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Rubick","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "skotski fold","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140920005" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Svinjica","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "samojed","cijepljen" => "NE", "chip" =>"HRV20141007006" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Aron","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "mastif","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20150102007" );
```

Is it possible to create search form using the form below for array above.I just want to get simple url value based on values that I input in search form. Let's say I want to search values for key "naziv" and if I write "Rubick"(naziv=>"Rubick") then I ll get value Rubick in url.

```
<form method="GET">
  Search Google:
  <input type="search" name="ljubimci_arr">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I tried using this example as working material but without any luck.
[Using Form Field to Search Php Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857642/using-form-field-to-search-php-associative-array#new-answer)

```
if(isset($_GET['year']))
{
    if(array_key_exists($_GET['year'], $ages))
    {
         echo $ages[$_GET['year']];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Cannot find data';
    }
}    
?>

<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="year" value="1984" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If I search for `Rubick`, you want to print out all the contents of the array that contains `Rubick`? Do you want to search only by the value of `naziv`?

Comment: I want to search only by value of naziv

Comment: And what do you want to return if found? All the values of the array? (`vrstva` and so on?)

Comment: If found just same writen value, if not found then 'Cannot find data'...

Comment: That answer was fine. Where did it go? :)

Comment: Just uploaded an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method loops through each item of your array and compares the input from your form to the values of the key `naziv`. If nothing is found, it prints out an error message.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Search Google:
    <input type="search" name="ljubimci_arr">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Stef","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "vucjak","cijepljen" => "DA","chip" =>"HRV20140115001" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Mia","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "tazmanijska zvijer","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140117002" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Jura","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "ruska plava","cijepljen" => "NE", "chip" =>"HRV20140216003" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Thepas","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "koker","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140823004" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Rubick","vrsta" => "Macka", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "skotski fold","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20140920005" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Svinjica","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "Z", "pasmina" => "samojed","cijepljen" => "NE", "chip" =>"HRV20141007006" );
$ljubimci_arr[]=array("naziv"=>"Aron","vrsta" => "Pas", "spol" => "M", "pasmina" => "mastif","cijepljen" => "DA", "chip" =>"HRV20150102007" );

if(isset($_POST['ljubimci_arr']))
{
    $found = 0;
    foreach($ljubimci_arr as $item) {
        if($item['naziv'] == $_POST['ljubimci_arr'])
        {
            print_r($item);
            $found = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!$found)
        echo "Cannot find data.<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you man! That's it! Thou , I do have question regarding previous answer.    if(isset($_POST['ljubimci_arr']))
    {
    $key = array_search($_POST['ljubimci_arr'], $ljubimci_arr);
    print_r($ljubimci_arr[$key]);
    // you can address different values like this: echo $ljubimci_arr[$key]   [0]
    } What was wrong with it?

Comment: It was wrong, it just echoed the first array and there was no constraint for the to be `naziv`.